# How to play Video in UIView using URL getting from server in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to play video in my UIView from the URL that i got from the JSON Response from server.

This is code that i wrote to play video but nothing happens.

```
 NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:objAlbum.strVideoURL];
 MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:self.movieView.bounds];  
[self.movieView addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];

// Configure the movie player controller
moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayerController play];
```

In strVideoURL i'm getting video url.

Comment: if you hardcode url, what happens?

Comment: are you getting an absolute URL path with an extension of the video format at the end? like -- `http://mywebserver.com/myvideo.mp4` or smthing like this

Comment: What is the URL value that you're getting from server ?

Comment: yes, saheb.    http://-------.---/demoVideo.mov

Comment: did you try moviePlayerController .movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming ?

Comment: No MACMAN, i don't want to implement with hardcode URL, its working fine with hardcode URL but i need to get URL from webservices and that URL i would like to play.

Comment: yes Huy Nghia, i tried this but video player shows blank. video dosen't play.

Comment: @TejasPatel are you able to play same video in safari browser in mobile? if not then surely your video codec has some issue while creating .mov. make sure your video is mobile compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Check that URL has any spaces. Better to Add below line of code

```
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[objAlbum.strVideoURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
 NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:self.movieView.bounds];  

// Configure the movie player controller
moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
//[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayerController play];
[self.movieView addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
```

**Note**: Print the movie URL and play using browser to check it is valid URL or not..!

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: Thanks for code, there is no error displaying but still not able to play video.

Answer (score 0):

i have solve this using following code

```
NSURL *vidURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:objAlbum.strVideoURL];

self.movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:vidURL];
self.movie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

self.movie.shouldAutoplay = YES;

[self.view addSubview:self.movie.view];
[self.movie setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

but i want to open it now in UIView defined in TableViewCell like video open in FB(Facebook)

Comment: you could use [AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/)